# Android app Publish Error

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, google-play, visual-studio-cordova

I am getting this Error when I try to publish this app in the store to an update of existing app. I am using Visual studio Apache Cordova Tools to build the apk and the previous version was published with Intel XDK

```
It is forbidden that a device upgrading from API levels in range 16-23 to API levels in range 24+ should downgrade from version 48 to version 9, which would occur when 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
Features containing all of [android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN].
```

Please let me know why I am getting this issue. Also possible solutions for this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

This is not due to the tool you used for build. I faced the same issue. Here is what I was trying to do.

1. I had my version 5 covering minSDK as 8 to maxSDK as 23.
2. I released a version 6 from 14 to 23. In this build I found that app was crashing for version from 14 to 20 but working fine above 21+
3. So I wanted to create a version 7 covering from 21+ and also enable version 5 in play store console so that rest of the devices running 14 to 20 also can be covered by version 5.

But since we have already published a version which has given coverage for devices running api 14 to 23, we are asking Google to downgrade those devices.

And that is why you see

"It is forbidden that a device upgrading from API levels in range 16-23 to API levels in range 24+ should downgrade from version 48 to version 9, which would occur when "

Please ensure you are not downgrading the devices running those api which you had given an updated version already. Check your build.gradle file or Manifest to confirm the same.

In my case, I solved this by fixing the issues causing the crash and released version 7 that works fine from API 14 to 23. Hope this helps.

Comment: my app was initially published with min sdk = 10 and Target = 19.
Now I am trying to publish the update for beta testing with same min sdk = 10  and target = 19 . I am changing nothing here except www folder contents and the build IDE from intel xdk to vs. I cant figure out why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed but what I did to fix is uncertain

I tried to update Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Apache Cordova (update 7) and also updated cordova to 5.4.1 and a rebuild fixed the issue in store.

so I am not sure what was the cause and what fixed it. but definitely just serveral rebuilds didnt fix though.

Hope this will help someone in future